# How to test subscriber in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactive

There is a `TestSubscriber` class in RxJaxa which allows me to apply assertions on how Upstream has sent the data. But consider a scenario where you want to actually test the subscriber that you have written. For example

```
class MySubscriber extends DefaultSubscriber<Person> {
    @Override
    public void onNext(Person person) {
       //update some class level variables based on person
    }
}
```

There can be multiple assertions based on what `onNext` is doing. I have been looking around but cant find any way out to test my Subscriber.